# Snort - Error while running

Tags: networking, pcap, snort, intrusion-detection

Running snort (in packet dump mode) with command `sudo snort -C snort.conf -A console -i eth0` a following problem occurred:

```
    --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
Snort BPF option: snort.conf
pcap DAQ configured to passive.
The DAQ version does not support reload.
Acquiring network traffic from "eth0".
ERROR: Can't set DAQ BPF filter to 'snort.conf' (pcap_daq_set_filter: pcap_compile: syntax error)!
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong option to load the configuration, it should be the lower case '-c'.

```
sudo snort -c snort.conf -A console -i eth0
```

Also, you can test your configuration with '-T' before running it:

```
sudo snort -T -c snort.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

just put "-i" before eth0 in command it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo service snort
ps ax|grep snortstart
```

The output I got was

> /usr/sbin/snort -m 027 -D -d -l /var/log/snort -u snort -g snort -c
>   /etc/snort/snort.conf -S HOME_NET=[192.168.0.0/16] -i enp4s0

The man page says
 -D     Run   Snort   in   daemon   mode.    Alerts    are    sent    to
              /var/log/snort/alert unless otherwise specified.

So when I drop the -D and add the -A

```
sudo /usr/sbin/snort -m 027 -d -l /var/log/snort -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -S HOME_NET=[192.168.0.0/16] -i enp4s0 -A console
```

Works for snort Version 2.9.7.0 GRE (Build 149)